# Conditional Formatting color changes for due dates within a month

Tags: excel, date, colors, formatting, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set up conditional formatting for documents so that their row changes color when a certain criteria is satisfied within a specific month.

The document in question has 30 days to be completed initially, and then every 90 days thereon after the first one. For example Admission date is 1/1/17; the document is due by 1/31/17, and the two week mark is 1/15/17. I have the spreadsheets tabbed on a monthly basis so I can get a statistical break down of admission rates/discharge rates/documents completed for that month, as well as any other information I might need to gather from it.

At first, I tried using the `=NOW()` formula; I can't seem to post the actual rules written out for whatever limitation this site has; just know that the order was:

- **Document expiration (90 day one) Yellow**
- **Document 2 week mark (90 day one) Orange**
- **A Stop if True rule to negate the color changes**
- **Document expiration (30 day one) red and white**
- **Document 2 week mark (30 day one) Dark orange and white**
- **Another Stop if True rule to negate the color changes**

The problem with this `NOW` or `TODAY` formula is that it makes checking back on a previous month's tab not viable. It's fine for the month you're in; if today's date is 1/23/17 and a person's document (90 days) is due on 2/1/17, it will display as orange as was designed. But once 2/1/17 hits, it will turn yellow, which I would not want it to do in the January tab; if anything, I would want all formatting to freeze (somehow) on the last day of January so that the data would reflect based on their expiration status on that last day.

This has been a confusing process for me and I have trouble really putting what I am doing into words (self-trained in excel; not super familiar with all of the jargon).

Answer (score 0):

try and use MIN(NOW();VALUE("2017-01-31")) for e.g. the January tab instead of NOW(). It will freeze at the 31st of January.

Comment: This looks promising; where do I place this formula and how does it interact with the conditional formatting?

Comment: use conditional formatting with on the admission date cell with a formula. Let's say the admission date cell is A2, then the formula to be put into the conditional formatting dialog would be =MIN(NOW();VALUE("2017-01-31"))-A2>90 for a ninety days limit. Apply the yellow fill format in the formatting dialog and add more formatting rules to the same cell for the other colors.

Comment: Oh this would be excellent! just to clarify, the admission date's only connection is to the very first treatment plan, which is a 30 day time limit. For the 90 day time limit, I had a T.P. start date column and a T.P. end date column that would reflect the data per client. To adapt this formula to that, would I do something like =MIN(NOW();VALUE("2017-01-31"))-N11>90 if N11 was the T.P. start date cell? Or would I put in N12, the T.P. end date cell?

Comment: I attempted the equation and the "formula you typed contains an error" window box popped up =/

Comment: try "NOW(),VALUE( ..." with a comma instead of a semicolon. I am using a German version, but you may have a different locale.